# success message not showing after jQuery form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have used following jQuery + AJAX for sending a form. It is posting the data to PHP but after success, is not showing the success message.

I would also like to empty the input fields after submission.

```
function sendContact() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var valid;

  valid = validateContact();
  if (valid) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "  ",

      data: 'userName=' + $("#userName").val() + '&userEmail=' + $("#userEmail").val() + '&subject=' + $("#subject").val() + '&content=' + $(content).val(),
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#mail-status").html(data);
        $('#mail-status').show();
        $("#frmContact").hide();

        // Clear the form.
        $('#userName').val('');
        $('#userEmail').val('');
        $('#content').val('');
      },
      error: function() {}
    });
  }
}

function validateContact() {
  var valid = true;
  $(".InputBox").css('background-color', '');
  $(".info").html('');

  if (!$("#userName").val()) {
    $("#userName-info").html("(required)");
    $("#userName").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
  }
  if (!$("#userEmail").val()) {
    $("#userEmail-info").html("(required)");
    $("#userEmail").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
  }
  if (!$("#userEmail").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
    $("#userEmail-info").html("(invalid)");
    $("#userEmail").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
  }
  if (!$("#content").val()) {
    $("#content-info").html("(required)");
    $("#content").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
    valid = false;
  }
  return valid;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="frmContact">
  <div id="mail-status" style="display: none;">
    Thanks! Our Admin 'll contact shortly.</div>

  <div>
    <label style="padding-top:20px;">Name</label><span id="userName-info" class="info"></span>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" class="InputBox">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Email</label><span id="userEmail-info" class="info"></span>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" class="InputBox">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Content</label><span id="content-info" class="info"></span>
    <br/>
    <textarea name="content" id="content" class="InputBox" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button name="submit" class="btnAction" onClick="sendContact();">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is your `url` field empty?

Comment: The URL is like "http://www.xxxx.abc/test/myform.php"

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js

Comment: Try putting an alert or console log inside the success handler to see if it least triggers or not. It might simply be your php returning incorrect data or no data at all.

Comment: PHP is working fine and getting all the data entered in the HTML form.

Comment: I'm not saying php isn't handling it fine. I'm saying to check if your success handler triggers or not. You're calling `$("#mail-status").html(data);`, but if `data` is empty there, nothing will happen right? So put an alert instead just to check if it at least triggers or not

Comment: And while you're add it, change `error: function() {}` to `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError); }` So that if something goes wrong, you're able to give us usefull information about it.

Comment: In that case, after successful submission, the pop-up window : page says:  0

Comment: XHR status 0 means there's a problem with the url you're trying to post data to. Most likely you're trying to post data cross-domain, which isn't allowed according to the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: @Mohan We've gone to some effort to help you. The major motivation to help others on this site is in earning rep. Leaving the question unresolved without giving any feedback is not cool. If there was some development, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4kLLa4zs/) fiddle.

There's a number of recommendations for changes I'd make along with some observations.

First of all, if your form *is a form*, then use the `form` element with your `#frmContact` id. It will be useful for several reasons:

```
<form id="frmContact" action="/echo/html/" method="POST">...</form>
```

1. We can now use the `action` and `method` attributes to govern its behaviour on submit. You can update the action to be the URL it should go to and the method - in this case is  POST.
2. Since it is a form, we can now trigger the `reset` event on it after successful submission, which handles your requirement of emptying the fields.
3. We can use `.serialize()` to collect all the form input data, so you don't need to go through your inputs manually selecting what you need and creating a query string.

JS:

```
$("#frmContact").on("submit", function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var form = this;

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: form.method,
    url: form.action,
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      $("#mail-status")
        .html(data)
        .show();

      $(form)
        .hide()
        .trigger("reset");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status) {
      console.log(xhr, status);
    }
  });
});
```

We don't necessarily need any validation function anymore. Just use the HTML5 attributes of `required` and `type=email` to validate the email address.

If you really need backward compatibility, by all means change this the way you want, but for a minimal reproducible version of your problem, it's far easier to disregard this in your question.

If you are still having problems, then please provide your PHP and update your question with any feedback from the console in your browser's developer tools console, and also provide your browser name and version.